# Double integral boundaries.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to find the area using double integral for the domain bounded by 
$$y=x^2$$
and
$$x-y+2=0.$$
Now, I want to find my integral boundaries:
I did $y=x^2, y=x+2$, solved this system and get
$$x_1=2,\quad x_2=-1.$$ 
Now I don't know how should my integration boundaries should be.

Is
$$\int_1^4\int_{-1}^2{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$$
or
$$\int_{x^2}^{x+2}\int_{-1}^2 {\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to find the area bounded above by a curve $y=g(x),$ below by a curve $y=f(x),$ on the left by $x=a$ and on the right by $x=b,$ then the integral will be $$\int_a^b\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}\,dy\,dx.$$ Can you apply that to the given situation and determine which is correct? (For "extra credit," can you determine the region for which the other is finding the area?)